# Jquery slideToggle next element with live()

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have the following snippet, but it doesn't work. Probably the live() handler is misplaced:

```
$('.link').next().hide().prev().live('click' ,function () {
$(this).next('.desc_hidden').slideToggle(100);
});
```

Thanks.
To understand this was the original, but as you can see it toggles every element, not just the next:

```
    $('.link').live('click' , function(){
$('.desc_hidden').slideToggle('100');
});
```

Update, the working code is here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ebatron/ueqz3/1/).
Thanks for everyone.

Comment: What is the `live` call meant to accomplish? Why don't you want to use a standard `bind` call?

Comment: "Probably the live() handler is misplaced:" Than we need corresponding HTML to help you out, don't we ?

Comment: Javascript generated content with list elements. All list element have a hidden div next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that starting from the second code snippet, you just want to have each `.link` to show the div next to it, you can use the following:

```
$('.link').live('click' , function(){
     $(this).next('.desc_hidden').slideToggle('100');
});
```

(this migth need some tweaks depending of your dom implementation).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, every list item has a link in it and under every list element there is a hidden div (not inside the li) I want to toggle. Unfortunately your snippet doesn't work, now I'm trying to find out what's wrong with it - because it looks okay...

Comment: Well there is a little test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/yMCEp/ . It works just fine, starting from that you can check what differs from yours. Or post the generating code/generated html.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the html on your code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ebatron/ueqz3/)

Comment: You just inverted the calls to next and parent.

$(this).parent().next('.desc_hidden').show(); works.

Comment: Thanks Py, I updated my question with the link of the working code.